# Changing background of div in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

my code have one div and three picture
my main task is to show the same image in div when I hover over any picture what I am not able to understand is how can I do it with variables so that if in future if add more pictures it does not make any problem for me
note:: I want to do it by using variables I don't want to hard code image source.
I am also attaching the image for reference only.

```js
function showproperties(element) {
  var x = document.getElementById("box001");
  x.innerHTML = element.alt;
  var y = element.src;
  document.getElementById("printsrc").innerHTML = y;
  x.style.backgroundImage = y;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="box001">main hover box

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="image001 imgresize">
      <img src="img01.jpg" alt="Image 001" onmouseover="showproperties(this)" onmouseleave="defaulttext(this)">
    </div>
    <div class="image002 imgresize">
      <img src="img02.jpg" alt="image 002" onmouseover="showproperties(this)" onmouseleave="defaulttext(this)">

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjzuy.png)

Comment: does `x.style.backgroundImage = \`url(${y})\`` work?

Comment: There is no element with id `printsrc` in this example, and `defaulttext()` is not provided. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue and made some changes in it. I Hope that's how you wanted it to work. I have used some gif images url for demo purpose.

**HTML:**

```
       <div id="box001" style="width: 100px;height: 100px; margin:7px">main hover box
      
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="image001 imgresize">
            <img src="https://c.tenor.com/Lvhj4QVL8-4AAAAS/server-is-for-javascript.gif" alt="Image 001" onmouseover="showproperties(this)" onmouseleave="defaulttext(this)">
          </div>
          <div class="image002 imgresize">
            <img src="https://c.tenor.com/FIcvxhgc1sgAAAAS/dit-is-een-code-blok-code.gif" alt="image 002" onmouseover="showproperties(this)" onmouseleave="defaulttext(this)">
      
          </div>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

```
var x = document.getElementById("box001");

function showproperties(element) {
  var y = element.src;
  x.innerText = "";
  x.style.backgroundImage = `url(${y})`;
}

function defaulttext(element) {
  x.innerText = "main hover box";
  x.style.backgroundImage = "none";
}
```

Full working code is available on this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0h1urctn/

Comment: x.style.backgroundImage = `url(${y})`; can we do this line with standard JS ??

Comment: yes. We can replace it with   ```x.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + y + ')';```

Comment: thank you can you provide any documentation for this 'url(' + y + ')' is this some sort of concatenation? i am not able to understand this line

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's a string concatenation with variables. 

You can check it here - https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/string-concat